# Django - get_list_or_404

Tags: python, django

I have a model in Django called Worlds which is linked via ForeignKey to a model: SolarSystem.
When I want to access the 'SolarSystem' object from a detailed view page, I want all of the 'Worlds' objects to be read on this same page or updated at any point from an edit page. The edit page gives the errors

> get() returned more than one WorldsModel -- it returned 2!

if I applied two 'worlds' model objects via the admin panel or

> Page not found (404)

if the SolarSystem has no 'Worlds' in it, and so it allows me to edit the information via the users view if there's just one world object that belongs to the specific solar system.

views.py:

```
solarsystem = get_object_or_404(SolarSystem, solar_slug=solar_slug)
queryset = SolarSystem.objects.filter(related_user=request.user.id, parent_system=solarsystem)
    try:
        worldlist = get_object_or_404(queryset)
    except Worlds.DoesNotExist:
        worldlist = None
user_profile = UserProfileModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)

if request.method == 'POST':
    
# this bit isn't relevant as request.method is GET
      
else:
    form = NewSystemForm(instance=solarsystem)
    worldsform = WorldForm(instance=worldlist)
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {'solarsystem':solarsystem,
                    'solar_slug':solar_slug,'form':form,'worldsform':worldsform,'user_profile':user_profile})
```

models.py:

```
class SolarSystem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, related_name='SolarSystem', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Title')
    solar_slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Slug', unique=True, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Solar System'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'solar_slug': self.solar_slug})

    def get_edit_url(self):
        return reverse('edit', kwargs={'solar_slug': self.solar_slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.user is None:
            self.user = UserModel.objects.get(id=1)
        super(SolarSystem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Worlds(models.Model):
    related_user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, related_name='Worlds', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    parent_system = models.ForeignKey(SolarSystem, related_name='Worlds', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    world_info = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='World Info', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'World'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.world_info

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.related_user is None:
            self.related_user = UserModel.objects.get(id=1)
        super(Worlds, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Anybody got any idea how to
a) Prevent the 404, given that the SolarSystem model doesn't necessarily have to have a 'Worlds' object for it to be updated and b) Allow multiple Worlds to be displayed and edited from within the edit view (so the number of form fields with instance data generated is equal to the number of Worlds???

**Edit**
Traceback after running into `'list' object has no attribute '_meta'` error:

```
> Internal Server Error: /dashboard/system/edit/0169411033/ Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 39, in inner
>     response = get_response(request)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 187, in _get_response
>     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 185, in _get_response
>     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/Users/jayt/okay/dashboard/views.py", line 75, in
> edit
>     worldform = WorldsForm(instance=worldlist)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/forms/models.py",
> line 282, in __init__
>     object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)   File
> "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/forms/models.py",
> line 87, in model_to_dict
>     opts = instance._meta AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not sure which version of Django you are using, I'm referencing Django 1.10 version. You are using `get_list_or_404` method, which automatically raises a 404 if the list is empty, so the exception is not being handled by your code. An alternative would be to use `filter` so you can manage the exception alone.

Sorry, but I can't understand why it raises

> get() returned more than one WorldsModel -- it returned 2!

Comment: I edited my views.py to filter the objects and pass it in to the get_object_or_404 with a variable queryset. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to remove the 404 error :( - not sure why this is happening!

Answer (score 0):

This logic is a little bit backwards.

```
    queryset = SolarSystem.objects.filter(related_user=request.user.id, parent_system=solarsystem)
    try:
        worldlist = get_object_or_404(queryset)
    except Worlds.DoesNotExist:
        worldlist = None
```

I think what you actually want to do is query on the `Worlds` model manager.

```
worldlist = list(Worlds.objects.filter(related_user=request.user.id, parent_system=solarsystem))
```

The `get_list_or_404` should fix your get returning multiple, but you also won't be able to catch the 404 error. Based on the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404), I would just use to filter on the manager if you want to be able to have an empty queryset.

EDIT: Update for your edit: The issue you have is that you are calling   `worldsform = WorldForm(instance=worldlist)`. I assume this is a ModelForm that you've written for `Worlds`. That should tak an instance of `World`, but you are passing this list. I suggest you call it with the instances inside the list.

Comment: This gets rid of the returns 2 error but seems to give the error ''list' object has no attribute '_meta'' - anything else I could be missing perhaps?

Comment: @jayt Where is it throwing the `_meta` error? Can you post the trace? My first guess is that you are passing the list somewhere, where you should be passing a `World` instance.

Comment: Updated my question to include the traceback.

Comment: Do you mean where (instance=World)? That let me render the pages properly but the form field is automatically populated with this as a string <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x10512ad50> for some reason.